# How to add two lines in box() contents of the box?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to have three lines of text contents in Box():
"Screened", "Big", "Small"

I don't know how to add lines in contents in Box().

```
fluidRow(box("line1", status = "primary", title = "Oral",  width = 6 , 
height = 120, background = "red"))
```

I want three lines in contents of the Box(): 
1. "line 1",
2. "line 2",
3. "line 3"

[infobox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORsyT.jpg)

Can anyone help on this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include any raw html inside the HTML function

```
box(HTML("line1: <br> line2: <br> line3: "), status = "primary", title = "Oral",  width = 6 , 
      height = 120, background = "red")
```